# Facebook iPhone application - launching icon effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios, ios4

is the launch icon effect standard in the iphone sdk?

If not which effect was used?

Ie when Messages icon is clicked the section of the message screen is zoomed up, then when the messages section is closed the section is zoomed out and returns back to the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's custom, though the framework is open source: https://github.com/facebook/three20

Take a look at the "launcher" stuff.

Comment: AFAIK It is standard on iPad though.

Comment: I think he's talking about inside the Facebook app, not the iOS springboard.